# Multitenancy using LDAP Integration

Tags: postgresql, jakarta-ee, multi-tenant

I need your suggestion for the following stuff of Multitenancy:

Actually I need to achieve multitenancy for my app. I've got it for using traditional flow with use of DB/Schema (eg. separate schema for each tenant).

Now I need to integrate user validation from LDAP and multitenancy stuff as well.
So What I am thinking is that If I store **User info + DB/Schema info (DB connectivity info)** in LDAP Server for more dynamic nature of the app. Because with this I would be able to connect any DB/Schema (irrespective of their physical location).

What's your opinion for this approach, Would it be really feasible? 
If there is any cons in your mind, please share.

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: are you talking about tenant in a PaaS or SaaS way? I mean; you are obviously talking about a Java EE application backed by an ee server. so you might not want to dynamically configure resources like LDAP (which normally have a tight integration into your server).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to host multiple clients' systems on your system and each client may have multiple connections from multiple locations.  From your question it sounds like you are putting one customer per database though databases may not be on the same cluster.

The first thing to do is to lock down PostgreSQL appropriately in the pg_hba.conf and expose only those database/user combos you want to expose.  If you are going this route, LDAP sounds sane to me for publishing the connection info, since it means you can control who can access which accounts.  Another option, possibly closely tied, would be to issue SSL certs and use certificate authentication by clients, so they can be issued a cert and use it to connect.  You could even authenticate PostgreSQL against LDAP.

So there are a lot of options here for using these two together once you have things otherwise properly secured.  Best of luck.